# Unknown Error on Web Host but code runs well on localhost

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I just had finished a form working in my localhost, it was working perfectly, but by the time I uploaded the code to the web host it wasn't working as it was supposed to. It is a simple form that uses PHP, MySQL and JQuery. When I click on submit it shows my custom error window saying that the email was registered already but the thing is that the database is empty. I put some code inside the ajax part that checks the email and this is what it says (it's supposed to show only a number):

**Warnings** : mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resources in  **/****/****/public_html/check_user.php**  on line  **17**

Here's check_user.php:

```
<?php
require_once("SqlChromoConnection.php");

// Check if email is not empty in the form
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // create the query
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
            FROM Users
            WHERE email = '" . trim($_POST['email']) . "'";

    // create object to handle the connection
    $conn = new SqlChromoConnection();
    $conn->getDatabaseConnection();     // establish a connection

    $data = $conn->executeQuery($sql);  // execute query
    $count= mysql_fetch_assoc($data);   // save result in $count
    $exists = $count['count'];      // access only the field 'count'

    $conn->closeConnection();       // close the connection

    echo $exists;

    exit(0);
}

?>
```

And here's the ajax part that checks the email:

```
if( !re.test(email) || email.indexOf(' ') > 0) {
            message = "Email NOT valid!!!";
            messageDialog("Warning", message, "warning", 2);
            return false;
        } else {
            // use ajax to check if a user has been previously registered
            // using this email
            var valid = false;

            $.ajax(
            {
                url:"check_user.php",   // url that will use
                async: false,
                data:{                  // data that will be sent
                    email:email
                },
                type:"POST",            // type of submision
                dataType:"text",        // what type of data we'll get back
                success:function(data)
                { 
                    window.alert(data);
                    // if check_user returns 0
                    // means that there's no any user registered with that email
                    if(data == 0 ) {
                        valid = true;
                    }
                }
            });

            if(!valid) {
                message = "This email is registered already!";
                messageDialog("Error", message, "error", 2);
                return false;
            }else return true;

        }
```

As I said, the code runs well when in localhost.

Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: your connection is failing to connect to the SQL server. Check the `mysql_error` when you're connecting to the server.

Comment: The mysql functions you are using are depreciated and will be removed from future versions of PHP.  Please use a relevant library of functions that include prepared statements.  http://in1.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: The form populates its drop down lists by accessing the database and retrieving the info, that part is working, so it makes me think that the connection to the SQL server is fine, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **@** before your **mysql_fetch_assoc** it removes all warning comes from this statement.
Use like **@mysql_fetch_assoc().**

Comment: Thanks! It worked. BUT now I have a new problem. It does register the user, but now if I try to add a user that had been previously added it doesn't show me the message saying it. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It worked! I use @ and using the answer from Nikhil Kudtarkar I got it to work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sebastian Using @ before any readymade function removes all the generated warning but it not removes error. If you want to show a error for user redundancy then use unique index in you db table or you can check user existence before creating new one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **users** Instead of **Users** for table name

Comment: I was using 'users', when I saw the error I changed to 'Users' to try to solve it but it didn't work, so I went back to 'users'

Comment: users.email? :| :|  
also try var_dump($sql) if it fails?

Comment: Hey Nikhil Kudtarkar. Your answer by itself didn't work at the beginning. I used @ as suggested by Himalya Vashistha (still don't understand what the problem was though) and it worked, I mean, it allowed me to create a non-existing user but when I tried to add an existing user it didn't show me any error, that's when I decided to change again to Users and it worked perfectly. I wish I could select both answers as accepted answer. Thanks a lot